# How can I prove the uniqueness of an ODE: $ -v''(x)+\frac{v(x)}{(1+v^2(x))^2}+v(x)=1 $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis

The question has been answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253996/how-do-i-show-the-following-ode-as-a-unique-solution-in-0-1/254009#254009)

---

Given the ODE
$$
-v''(x)+\frac{v(x)}{(1+v^2(x))^2}+v(x)=1
$$
satisfies the condition $x\in(0,1)$, $v(0)=v(1)=1$, and $v(\cdot)$ is symmetric with respect to $1/2$.

---

I am wondering that can we determine the solution $v$ uniquely such that the above condition satisfies? This ODE is not linear nor any standard form so I am not quiet sure about it...although the two boundary condition is given. Moreover, I know $v$ is non-negative and [quasi-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function).

Typically, by quasi-convexity and symmetricity, we have $v$ is monotone decreasing in $(0,1/2)$ and monotone increasing in $(1/2,1)$.

However, I am still not so sure that the uniqueness...

Comment: Note that multiplying by $v'$ you can integrate and get
$$-v'^2-\frac1{1+v^2}+v^2=2v+\text{Constant}.$$

Comment: One way to handle uniqueness theory for BVPs is to introduce $v'(0)$ as a parameter. For each value of this parameter you (usually) have uniqueness, and then you use some argument to conclude that the BC on the right can only hold for a particular value of the parameter. One way to do this here would be to analyze the min/max behavior of the function $f(x)=1-x-\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$. These tell you how the second derivative can change sign, if at all. Note that this matters because by Rolle's theorem the *first* derivative must also change sign.

Comment: In this case the second derivative is an increasing function of $v$ and it is initially positive. So if $v'(0)$ is negative but not too huge, then you can imagine a solution to the DE which is convex and will ultimately pass through $1$ at $1$. (Qualitatively such a thing would look like $(x-1/2)^2+3/4$ or something like this.) Other solutions would have to be more complicated with some sign change in the second derivative and therefore a sign change in $v$ itself.

Comment: @Ian thank you for your suggestions! I actually know for instance that $v$ is non-negative and convex...I just update it in my post

Comment: Since you know $v$ is convex, it should be the case that $v(1)$ is a monotone function of $v'(0)$ in the range of values of $v'(0)$ which ensure convexity. This, in combination with Picard-Lindelof, will give you a unique *convex* solution even though it doesn't guarantee that there are no nonconvex solutions.

Comment: @Ian I checked the reference but I can't really come up with an answer... and I relize that my function is quasiconvex but not convex as I edited in my question. Could you detail you comment as an answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By Theorem 7.7 (described in "The Theory of Differential Equations" by Walter Kelley and Allan Peterson, page 313), this BVP has a unique solution.

[Note that using this theorem, no appeal needs to be made to the: symmetry, non-negativity, and/or quasi-convex properties mentioned.]

In the language of the theorem quoted, we have:

$$v''(t)=f(t,v)\text{ where } f(t,v)=f(v)=\frac{v}{(1+v^2)^2}+v-1$$

Here $f(t,v)$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$ and satisfies the (Lipschitz) condition:

$$|f(t,x) − f(t,y)| = |f(x) - f(y)| ≤ K|x − y|$$ where $K=2$.

[Reason:  $|f′(v)| ≤ 2$ for all $v$ in $\mathbb{R}$, so the MVT implies $|f(x) - f(y)|/|x - y| = |f′(\text{squiggle})|$ (for some squiggle in the interval $(x , y)$ ).]

Thus, by the theorem, as long as the two boundary conditions specified are close enough together (specifically, as long as $b-a < \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{K}}$ ), the given BVP has a unique solution.

Here $a=0$ and $b=1$, so $b-a = 1 < 2 = \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{K}}$, so we do have a unique solution.